# Некорректная выборка в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос

**Что имеем:**

СУБД PostgreSQL 12

Есть три таблицы

`worker` - работники 
`id | name`

`work` - расписание на каждый день.
`id | worker_id | date | time_from | time_to | is_weekend | time_to |`

`work_except` - исключение в расписании на конкретный день.
`id | worker_id | date | time_from | time_to | is_weekend | time_to |`

**Что нужно:**

На конкретный день получать список работников в котором:

- В начале списка будут те, кто выходят на работу в промежутке с `time_from` по `time_to` по основному графику не имея исключением выходной в этот день:
  `work.is_weekend = False AND (work_except.is_weekend = False OR work_except.is_weekend IS NULL)`
- Далее по списку те, у кого по расписанию был выходной, но они в качестве исключения выходят на работу:
  `work.is_weekend = True AND work_except.is_weekend = False`
- Далее по списку те, у кого выходной или те, кто его взяли. По сути все остальные:
  `work.is_weekend = True OR work_except.is_weekend = True`

Дубликатов быть не должно.

**Что делал:**
Для начала я соединяю `LEFT INNER JOIN` последовательно таблицы `worker` <-- `work` (по `worker_id`) <-- `work_except` (по `worker_id`).

Попытка через фильтрацию:

Делал выборку по `date` и времени в обеих таблица и сортировки по `work.is_weekend` и `work_except.is_weekend DESC`

Однако это не подошло, так как согласно сортировке возвращался список где сначала
`work.is_weekend = FALSE` и `work_except.is_weekend IS NULL` - это ОК
Далее `work.is_weekend = FALSE` и `work_except.is_weekend = True` - уже неверно согласно требованиям
Далее `work.is_weekend = TRUE` и `work_except.is_weekend IS NULL` - тоже неверно согласно требованиям
Далее `work.is_weekend = TRUE` и `work_except.is_weekend = FALSE` - тоже неверно согласно требованиям

```
SELECT
    work.id,
    work_except.id,
    work.time_from,
    work.time_to,
    work.is_weekend,
    work_except.is_weekend
FROM couriers c
    LEFT JOIN worker ON worker.id = work.worker_id
    LEFT JOIN work_except ON worker.id = work_except.worker_id
WHERE
        work.date = <some_date> AND
        work_except.date = <some_date> AND
        work.time_from >= '10:00:00' AND
        work.time_to <= '20:00:00'
ORDER BY
        cws.is_weekend,
        cwse.is_weekend DESC;
```

Попытка 2.
Пробовал воспользоваться отдельными запросами с условиями объединёнными `UNION`.
Но там стали вовсе выпадать некоторые записи и с сортировкой проблемы.

Подскажите как можно решить эту задачу и какой подход лучше использовать?

*P.S. Активно мониторию вопрос. Если необходимы пояснения, пишите, сразу отвечу.*

Comment: Насколько вижу, конкретно в этом запросе таблица `worker` не нужна?

Comment: @Ainar-G , этим  можно принебречь, но желательно чтобы было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оригинальном вопросе нет информации о том, по каким
условиям объединяются отношения `work`
и `work_except`. Точнее, есть наверняка неверный ответ
«по `work_except.worker_id = work_except.worker_id`»,
что не является достаточным условием, так как у одного
работника скорее всего несколько дней.

Если предположить, что настоящим условием объединения являются
работник **и даты**, то остаётся всего лишь ввести
отдельное сортировочное поле:

```sql
WITH all_work AS (
  SELECT work.*
       , COALESCE(work_except.is_weekend, FALSE) AS is_except
    FROM work
    LEFT JOIN work_except
      ON work.worker_id = work_except.worker_id
     AND work.time_from = work_except.time_from
     AND work.time_to = work_except.time_to
     AND work.date = work_except.date
)
SELECT *
     , CASE
         WHEN NOT is_weekend AND NOT is_except THEN 1
         WHEN is_weekend AND NOT is_except     THEN 2
         ELSE 3
       END AS sort_order
  FROM all_work
 ORDER BY sort_order
;
```

[*Fiddle*](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgb9L5iZrYKAENrcjskMfK/0).

Дальше можно добавлять условия по дате и времени.

Comment: Спасибо. Смог успешно адаптировать под свои нужды.